# How to get **the product** of two matrices AB if they are placed into a **determinant** ?

Tags: linear-algebra

I just got stuck with a question

if there is : **det(AB)** .. and **det(A)= 4**  .. **det(B)=5**

the question is how to get the product of the two matrices AB inside the determinant  ?

Comment: Do you know any of determinant properties?

Answer (score 1):

In general, $\det AB = \det A \det B$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\det(\mathbf{AB})=\det(\mathbf{A})\det(\mathbf{B})$$
Do tell me if you want a proof.

Comment: so the product must be 20 right?

Comment: @Maher Yes, you're right. The **determinant** of the product is $20$.

Comment: if there is a proof,, that will be very helpful for me !

Comment: @Maher See [this link](http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-PDM.html).